# PHP adding empty text node before including html file

Tags: php

I'm using php as templating engine, and I've noticed that when I include view file, empty text node is added before content of that view.

For example, I have html file I want to include that has following content:

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

than I include that file like this:

```
<div><?php require_once('file/path.htm'); ?></div>
```

(notice that I've removed any spaces between div and php) And after php includes file he adds empty text node (which I'll mark like this "") that adds space before p tag, so I get something like this:

```
Some previous content...
<div>    
"" //empty text node
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

This is quite problematic since it ruins content composition. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Does the same happen without the `require_once`, i.e. if the `<div>` just contains the `<p>` statically? Make sure that there is not whitespace before the opening `<?php` of any PHP script, and you should be able to omit any closing `?>` as well.

Comment: In your example the empty text node is *before* the div while your complaint suggests the empty text node is *inside* the div (before the p). I presume that's just a small mistake in your code example? Otherwise the code before your example would be relevant.

Comment: Yes, sorry it's a mistake. No it doesn't happen if I don't have `require_once`.

Comment: Is there empty leading space in the html file you are loading?  you could `trim` the contents loading it via `file_get_contents()` rather than including it if there are no parsed php vars within.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado, no there's no empty space in file I'm including.

Comment: how does whitespace "ruins content composition"? Html ignores whitespace. Either directly, or because of other files you are including there will be whitespace in the file(s) you are including.

Comment: It is just a thought, but have you checked about BOM in both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem right now, and i had a luck when find answer. There answer is in charset. It could be strange, but when you save your file in UTF-8, you have empty  in your markup. When your file in cp1251, you dont have this problem.

Answer (score 5):

FSou1 has it right, it's the charset, it can also be solved by saving as UTF-8 without BOM:

1. Open your PHP inlcude file in Notepad++ (download here: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
2. Select Encoding --> Encode in UTF-8 without BOM

Empty nodes disappear. Hope that helps someone. This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This was my second issue caused by BOM (both took over an hour of debugging, Googling and hairpulling).
I just found this (windows-only) small drag and drop program that check for BOM which it can remove:

> **File BOM Detector** by **Brynt Younce**
>
> - [Softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/File-BOM-Detector.shtml](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/File-BOM-Detector.shtml)

Small, easy and simple. There seems to by a PHP solution for all platforms bu I have not tested it.
Take a look if interested:

> - [Github.com/emrahgunduz/BomCleaner](https://github.com/emrahgunduz/BomCleaner)